# How to extract subtitle from video using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, extract, subtitles

I am trying to extract subtitle from video as `.srt` file, I used the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i mytestmovie.mkv -vn -an -codec:s:0.1 srt sub.srt
```

But, I got an error as Unrecognized option `codec:s:0:1`
So, can you tell me the exact command and how to extract a subtitle as `.srt` file in video?

Answer (score 155):

Simple:

```
ffmpeg -i Movie.mkv -map 0:s:0 subs.srt
```

- [-i](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Main-options): Input file URL/path.
- [-map](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Advanced-options): Designate one or more input streams as a source for the output file.
- [s:0](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-specifiers): Select the subtitle stream.

Comment: This would download the first subtitle track. If there are several, use `0:s:1` to download the second one, `0:s:2` to download the third one, and so on.

Comment: @jm3 Would you happen to know any way to automatically extract all subtitle streams from a file, naming them after their language identifier (e.g. eng, fre, dut etc.)?

Comment: why is it so slow when extracting from big MKV container (~4 gb)?

Comment: To extract more subtitles at once you have to duplicate the `-map` parameters for each file. Also include `-c copy` so that it just extracts the file without trying to process it: `ffmpeg -i Movie.mkv -c copy -map 0:s:0 subs.01.srt -c copy -map 0:s:1 subs.02.srt`. Anyway it will take long time because ffmpeg must read whole video file to find all parts of the subtitle streams.

Comment: @RadekPech Why would it try to process it? Or rather I guess it can't not process it since you extract it into a file. As such, what's wrong with the default "processor"?

Comment: @x-yuri FFMPEG's default action is to process (convert) everything on input. Which means if you don't use `-c` parameter, it will automatically select a codec (or output format for subtitles - and FFMPEG actually CAN convert subtitle formats!) and process it. It may look OK to convert SRT into SRT, but it may mess up the input file if it contains something bad or unknown (wrong encoding, typo in timecode, overlapping or too short subtitles, etc.). So you should always include `-c copy` if want a 100% copy of the input.

Comment: doesn't work, says that it matches no stream, and VLC does see subtitles

Comment: What the hell, I tried it on a MP4 file and it extracts the subtitles with EXTRA BIG XXXXL font size (39pt), totally different / bigger size as how it is displayed when playing the mp4 file.

Comment: If extraction fails with error `[srt @ 0000021dae3c2a40] Unsupported subtitles codec: mov_text` then use `ffmpeg -i Movie.mkv -c copy -map 0:s:0 -codec:s srt subs.01.srt ...`

Answer (score 15):

```
ffmpeg -i video.mkv subs.srt
```

Wicked, right?

Worked for me just now, for a bunch of MKVs containing a single SRT stream. Apparently this is the default behavior. My ffmpeg version is 20170516, from ubuntu 16.4

Answer (score 13):

`-codec:s:0:1` is incorrect. If you use `-codec:s:0` then ffmpeg will use the stated codec for the first subtitle stream being passed to the output, if you use `-codec:s:1` then it will use it for the second subtitle stream, etc.

You can also use `-codec:s` to select *all* output subtitle streams, or `-codec:2` to select the third output stream, regardless of what it is.

You are probably confused because the `-map` option behaves in a different way - there, you have to select which input the selected stream comes from. (so, `-map 0:s:0` would take the first subtitle stream from the first input, and feed it to the output). However, `-map` is for selecting which streams you want to take from the inputs; whereas most of the other options that use stream mapping are for use on the streams after they have been selected (so there's no need to specify which input file they're from), as they are passed to the output.

Comment: evilsoup:i would using the following command  
E:\FFMpeg_Latest>ffmpeg -i E:\Routine\routine.mkv -vn -an -map 0:s:0 srt E:\Routine\sub.srt,it seems an error i got  Unable to find a suitable output format for 'srt',can u tell me the command for extracting an subtitle in video...

Comment: Try: `ffmpeg -i E:\Routine\routine.mkv -map 0:s:0 E:\Routine\sub.srt` (ffmpeg should detect that you want srt subtitles from the output file name)

Comment: I used:
  `ffmpeg -i film.mp4  -vn -an -codec:s srt film.srt`
that should copy all the subtitles to the srt file.

Comment: @Stuart it doesn't extract all subtitles

Comment: @evilsoup `-codec:s` so what is the point to use it if it's not going to extract all subtitles at the time? `-codec:s:idx` seems only this will work? but this way we have to execute this command many times to extract all subtitles

Comment: @evilsoup `-codec:s` is equal to `-codec:s:0` so it doesn't select all subtitles... it will extract first text track

Comment: @evilsoup Neither `-codec:s` nor `codec:s:0` "selects" anything. Both tell `ffmpeg` which codec to _apply_ to an _output_ stream, or streams, of subtitles. The `-map` option is used to select the stream(s) from the source. To select all the subtitle streams, without knowing how many there are, or their indices, use `-map 0:s` and if there may, or may not, be any subtitles, the map can be optional, and not cause `ffmpeg` to fail by using `-map 0:s?` See the [Advanced Options](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Advanced-options) in the `ffmpeg` docs.

Answer (score 5):

**Case 1 - a single subtitle in the video:**

```
# as by Berry Tsakala
> ffmpeg -i video.mkv subs.srt
```

**Case 2 - multiple subtitles:**

```
> ffprobe video.mkv
Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Main)...
Stream #0:1(rus): Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz...
Stream #0:2(eng): Audio: eac3, 48000 Hz...
Stream #0:3(rus): Subtitle: subrip
Stream #0:4(eng): Subtitle: subrip <-- wanted subs
Stream #0:5(eng): Subtitle: subrip
Stream #0:6(eng): Subtitle: subrip
```

Then if you want stream `0:4`, then just use `0:4`:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mkv -map 0:4 subs.srt
```

The `0:s:0` notion looks pretty useless in this case for me, because it makes us calculating in our heads.

Answer (score 1):

If the subtitles are separately muxed into the MP4, and not hardcoded, I always use `mkvmerge -o output.mkv theinput.mp4`. Then use `mkvextract tracks output.mkv 2:thetrackidof.vob`.

Then use `vobsub2srt thetrackidof` (with "thetrackidof" being the file name of the subtitle files without IDX or VOB file extensions). Works every time.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Made this bash script for a console phobic friend. It presents a `zenity` file chooser for video file selection. It then uses `ffmpeg` to pull all the subtitle tracks out as `srt` files named `"VIDEO_NAME-TRACK-LANG.srt"`. Added a desktop file so it could be started from the apps menu. Feel free to use as you wish:

- [https://github.com/ligelowbee/subtitle-dump.sh/](https://github.com/ligelowbee/subtitle-dump.sh/blob/main/subtitle-dump.sh)

Answer (score -1):

updated the code to v6 ver.

work pretty good.

usage:

ffmpegSubExtract Mp4 Srt

ffmpegSubExtract mkv Srt 1

```
@echo off
cls
title ffmpegSubExtract TOOL

if "%1"=="" (
echo.
echo Usage:
echo ffmpegSubsubExtract mp4 srt
echo ffmpegSubsubExtract mp4 srt 1
goto :eof )

if "%2"=="" (
echo.
echo Usage:
echo ffmpegSubsubExtract mp4 srt
echo ffmpegSubsubExtract mp4 srt 1
goto :eof )

set fleExt=%1
set subExt=%2
set stream=%3

for %%i in ("*.%fleExt%") do (
    set fname=%%i
    call :process
    )
    
goto :eof

:process
if exist "%fname:~0,-4%.%subExt%" (
    del "%fname:~0,-4%.%subExt%" )

if "%stream%"=="" (
    set stream=0 )


if "%subExt%" == "srt" (
    title ffmpegSubExtract TOOL ~ SubRip mode
    ffmpeg -i "%fname%" -map 0:s:%stream% "%fname:~0,-4%.%subExt%"
) else (
    title ffmpegSubExtract TOOL ~ "%subExt%" mode
    ffmpeg -i "%fname%" -c copy -map 0:s:%stream% "%fname:~0,-4%.%subExt%" 
)

goto :eof
```